# Curl of vector triple product.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I want to prove that for given constant vectors **A** and **B**

Curl [ (**R** × **A**) ×**B** ] = **B** × **A**

where **R** = xi + yj + zk

I proved vector triple product using index notation but I don't know how to approach the above problem using index notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [BAC-CAB identity](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BAC-CABIdentity.html):
$$
    (\mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{A}) \times \mathbf{B}
    = - (\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}) \mathbf{R} + (\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{R}) \mathbf{A}
$$
Now you can use the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Curl_2) for the curl of a scalar times a vector:
$$
   \nabla((\mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{A}) \times \mathbf{B})
   = - \nabla(\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}) \times \mathbf{R}
     - (\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}) (\nabla \times \mathbf{R})
     + \nabla(\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{R}) \times \mathbf{A}
     + (\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{R}) (\nabla \times \mathbf{A})
$$
Since $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are constant, $\nabla (\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}$ and $\nabla \times \mathbf{A}$ are zero.  Also, $\nabla \times \mathbf{R} = \mathbf{0}$ by calculation.  The only thing left to show is that $\nabla(\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{R}) = \mathbf{B}$, but this is straightforward.

---

If you want to use index notation, let $\mathbf{e}_1 = \mathbf{i}$, $\mathbf{e}_2 = \mathbf{j}$, and $\mathbf{e}_3 = \mathbf{k}$.  So we can write $\mathbf{A} = a_i \mathbf{e}_i$ and $\mathbf{B} = b_i \mathbf{e}_i$ (Einstein summation).  Write $x_1 = x$, $x_2 = y$, $x_3 = z$, so $\mathbf{R} = x_i \mathbf{e}_i$.  Let $\epsilon_{ijk}$ be the Levi-Civita tensor, so that
$$
    \mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B} = \epsilon_{ijk} a_i b_j \mathbf{e}_k
$$
For each $i$, write $\partial_i  = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$.  Notice that $\partial_i x_j = \delta_{ij}$, where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta tensor.  And if $\mathbf{F} = F_i \mathbf{e}_i$ is a vector field, then
$$
    \nabla \times \mathbf F = \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_i F_j \mathbf{e}_k
$$

Now 
\begin{align*}
   \nabla \times ((\mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{A}) \times \mathbf{B})
   &= \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_i ((\mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{A}) \times \mathbf{B})_j \mathbf{e}_k \\
   &= \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_i (\epsilon_{\ell mj} (\mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{A})_\ell b_m)\mathbf{e}_k \\
   &= \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_i (\epsilon_{\ell mj} \epsilon_{rp\ell}x_r a_p  b_m) \mathbf{e}_k\\
   &= \epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{\ell mj} \epsilon_{rp\ell} \partial_i x_r a_p  b_m \mathbf{e}_k\\
   &= \epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{\ell mj} \epsilon_{rp\ell} \delta_{ir} a_p  b_m \mathbf{e}_k\\
   &= \epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{\ell mj} \epsilon_{ip\ell} a_p  b_m \mathbf{e}_k\\
\end{align*}
Use the contraction identity on the first and last symbol (they both start with $i$):
$$
    \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ip\ell} = \delta_{jp}\delta_{k\ell} - \delta_{j\ell}\delta_{kp}
$$
And notice that:
\begin{align*}
    \epsilon_{\ell mj}\delta_{jp}\delta_{k\ell} &= \epsilon_{kmp} \\
    \epsilon_{\ell mj}\delta_{j\ell}\delta_{kp} &= \epsilon_{\ell m\ell} = 0
\end{align*}
So finally:
$$
\nabla \times ((\mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{A}) \times \mathbf{B})
    = \epsilon_{kmp} a_p b_m \mathbf{e}_k
    = \epsilon_{mpk} b_m a_p \mathbf{e}_k
    = \mathbf{B} \times \mathbf{A} 
$$

I'll point out that the contraction identity for the Levi-Civita tensor is essentially BAC-CAB in index notation.

Comment: Actually I got the answer following the same method as yours, but I was interested in solving it using index notations.

Comment: Oh, I read your post in the opposite fashion: that had proved it using index notation but you wanted a different approach.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. That cleared my doubt. I didn't substituted dixj with kronecker delta term and got stuck with di at last.